# Split given array into k sub arrays such that maximum sum of all sub arrays is minimum

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to tackle the above problem where I have an array e.g. [1,2,3,4,5] and I want to split it into k subarrays such that the max size of those subarrays is the minimum possible
e.g. for k = 3 that would be:

```
[5] [4,1] [3,2] 
max(...) = 5
```

The only similar thing that I could find is:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-the-given-array-into-k-sub-arrays-such-that-maximum-sum-of-all-sub-arrays-is-minimum/

But it does not give a correct result with the example above and it does not return the arrays, which is something that is needed in my case.

Ideally I want to do this in Python, but also pseudocode would work

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: *max size of those subarrays is the minimum possible e.g. for k = 3 that would be:*, I cannot understand this. Can you please elaborate a little

Comment: I think OP means that he wants to find a _partition_ of the arrays such that max( sum(elements of array i)) is minimized.

Comment: The solution you link to is different to what you want to do. They only consider _splitting_ the array, but _without rearranging_ the elements!

Comment: @Lagerbaeris is correct on both. Their solution is wrong but it was the closests thing I could find

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of length *L* and need to separate into *k* subsets you'll end up with *n = (L-L%k) / k* sub arrays of length *L' = int(L/k)* and one of length *l' = L%k*. If you sort the array, `x = np.sort(x)`, the sub array with length *l'* will be the one with the rightmost element of `x` and *l'-1* leftmost elements. The other *n* arrays are constructed in an analogous way, always with the rightmost combined with *L'-1* leftmost elements.

I believe this should give the right answer because the rightmost element will always be the largest, and the smallest combination is always with the leftmost elements left in the array. Any other combination is equal or greater.

In your example the array is already sorted, and it should give *l' = 1* with the `5`, *n = 2* of length *L' = 2*, which would be `[4,1]` and then `[3,2]`.